# How to pass a value from a runnable thread once it has finished in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio, android-threading

I am using a thread to get an id from my database. Once the thread has finished running I need to use that id in another thread to get a list of items. Once that thread has finished I use the list of items to populate a spinner. The problem I am encountering is that it is populating the spinner before the thread has returned the list of items. How can I make it so the spinner doesn't get populated until the thread has finished running?

```
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        String bookName = existingBooks.get((int) spinner.getSelectedItemId());

                        Book myBook = AppDatabase.getInstance(getContext()).bookDAO().getBookByTitle(bookName);

                        long book_Id = myBook.getBook_id();

                        existingCountDates = AppDatabase.getInstance(getContext()).countDAO().getCountDatesInBook(book_Id);

                        List<Count> Counts = AppDatabase.getInstance(getContext()).countDAO().getAllCounts();

                        Log.e("Dates", existingCountDates.toString());
                        Log.e("All Counts", Counts.toString());

                    }
                }).start();

                //TODO: FIX THIS ISSUE
                Log.e("Problem:", "This gets called before the thread finishes. Not sure how to fix it");
                str_adapter.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < existingCountDates.size(); i++) {
                    str_adapter.add(existingCountDates.get(i));
                }
                str_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                //TODO: DISABLE OTHER DROPDOWN MENUS?
            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use another thread and wait previous thread till finish using thread.join(). bu better version is use [ExecutorServices](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService) such as for instance the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor).

[CODELAB](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view#7)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will help you or not. But you can use a bool variable to check whether the thread has finished its work.

```
bool flag = false;
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //statements
        flag = true;
    }
}).start();
while(flag != true);
//statements to be executed after completion of thread.
```

NOTE: Make sure execution never goes to infinite loop.

Comment: This helped me to figure out what my real problem was. I also didn't know how to pass Data from a thread to the main UI Thread. I didn't realize that was what I didn't know how to do until I used your code. So thanks!

Comment: Any value that is changed by a thread must be marked as `volatile`.  Also it is really bad form to have a `while()` spin loop.  I know it is demonstration code but this sort of thing tends to be copied into a working project.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make it so the spinner doesn't get populated until the thread has finished running?

There are a couple of ways to do that.  The easiest might be to get an `ExecutorService` which is usually recommended as opposed to creating a `Thread` "by hand".  This also allows you to return a value from your job in which case you submit a `Callable<?>` instead of a `Runnable`.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
...
Future<Void> future = threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       ...
    }
});
// wait for this job to finish
future.get();
...
// when you are done with the pool you need to shut it down
threadPool.shutdown();
```

You can also start a thread and then `join()` with it.  That waits for the thread to finish.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() { ... });
thread.start();
// now we can do stuff while the thread runs in the background
...
// wait for the thread to finish before returning
thread.join();
...
```

The `get()` method or the `join()` method also means that the `existingCountDates` or anything else that was modified inside of the job will be updated in the caller's memory appropriately.